# Spring JPA EclipseLink config with java throws Cannot perform exception translation

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

I am trying to config eclipselink with spring jpa in java not in XML.

Here is my config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
class ApplicationConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trail");
    dataSource.setUsername("user1");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

    EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
    jpaProperties.put("jpaDialect"," org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect");
    factory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.trail.jpatest");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
    factory.setJpaDialect(new EclipseLinkJpaDialect());

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
}
@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
}
```

User Bean :

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String userName;
}
```

When I run this code in Spring MVC, I am getting an exception that `<I>Cannot perform exception translation</I>`

Please suggest me, what I am missing.

Is my understating of adding `<I>PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor</I>`
will not solve?

Is there any pointer for configuration of eclipselink in java with spring jpa ?

Exception I am getting :

```
Apr 27, 2014 10:43:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [com/trail/jpatest/ApplicationConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 31 more
```

xml file :

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.trail."/>
```

Comment: Please, post the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your configuration:

```
@Bean
public EclipseLinkJpaDialect eclipseLinkJpaDialect() {
   return new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working. I am not able vote up as i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Your welcome! Don't worry about the upvote! Accepting is what really counts since it provides future viewers with an easy way to know whether or not the proposed solution works