# Spring Data JPA - Why do I get null bean exception in the test?

Tags: java, jpa, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

I want to use Spring Data JPA to do the ORM. I have the following declared repository interface:

```
public interface SegmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Segment, Integer> {
    // query methods ...
}
```

Following is the Java Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.cap.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class CAPRepositoryConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getName());
        ds.setUsername("postgres");
        ds.setPassword("password");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        ds.setInitialSize(10);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.cap.repositories");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

And the `Segment` class is defined in `com.example.cap.repositories` as:

```
@Entity
public class Segment {
    @Id
    private int segmentID;
    private int caseID;
    private Timestamp segStartTime;
    private Timestamp segEndTime;

    //setter and getters
}
```

But when I run the JUnit test using auto injected bean `SegmentRepository`, I got null point exception for the bean `repository`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CAPRepositoryConfig.class)
public class CAPRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private SegmentRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testRepository() {
        Segment seg = repository.findOne(123);    //null pointer exception for repository
    }
}
```

According to the Spring Data JPA documentation, the `SegmentRepository` bean `repository` should be auto injected as long as I specify `@EnableJpaRepositories` in the Java Config class. But why do I get null pointer exception for `repository` in the JUnit test class? Since `SegmentRepository` is an interface rather than a class, I cannot create the instance through Java Config class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` which makes `@Autowired` in tests work:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CAPRepositoryConfig.class)
public class CAPRepositoryTest { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the NullPointerException. But I got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` when I run the JUnit test. It also shows `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.` So what is the problem here?

Comment: Try to return `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` from your `@Bean` method directly, without calling `getObject()`. Then you can pass `EntityManagerFactory` to `transactionManager()` as a method argument.

Comment: I found the problem. It is due to a missing bean for EclipseLink in the Java Config as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319864/spring-jpa-eclipselink-config-with-java-throws-cannot-perform-exception-translat?rq=1). But I still got an exception for type mismatch between the `segmentID` field in my `Segment` class and the data field in my PostgreSQL table `segmentID` which is defined as a `segmentID serial`. What Java type should I give to `segmentID` to match the `serial` type in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I think `int` should be fine, but I'm not familiar with EclipseLink

Comment: Thanks axtavt. I found out that his may be due to a bug in EclipseLink. I need to change the field from `int segmentID` to `Integer segmentID` to match the `@Id` annotation. But again I got another exception: `Error creating bean with name 'segmentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException`. Do you know what may cause this? What `init` method do I need to specify? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

When I work with test classes and I need to do an unit test, I prefer instantiate the class because although you have an interface you need to have to an implementation class too. In my case I do something like this:

```
 @ContextConfiguration(classes=CAPRepositoryConfig.class)
 public class CAPRepositoryTest {

     private SegmentRepository repository;

     @Before
     public void testRepository() {
         repository = new SegmentRepositoryImpl();
     }

     @Test
     public void testRepository() {
         Segment seg = repository.findOne(123);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think one should implement the Repository class in Spring Data JPA. It should be automatically handled by the framework.